# CKAN Development Install Issue: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'css/main.debug.css'

Tags: ckan

I've done a CKAN development install and am running with debug = true in my development.ini file. On visiting localhost:5000 I get an error with a traceback whose end point is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'css/main.debug.css'
```

Caused by the call in lib/helpers.py:

```
r = getattr(fanstatic_resources, resource)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and what I can do to fix this error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to run the `less` script from the `bin` directory in the CKAN source code to build the `main.debug.css` file. There is [some documentation of this](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/frontend-development.html) but it's not yet integrated with the rest of the CKAN docs (i.e. there's no link to it anywhere, we have a ticket to fix this).

This works on Ubuntu 12.04, you might need to have your virtualenv active when you do this:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
npm install less nodewatch
./bin/less # Assuming you're in your ckan dir e.g. `~/pyenv/src/ckan`
```

Now restart the `paster serve development.ini` command and it should work.

Generally speaking whenever running CKAN 2.0 for development you should:

- Have `debug = True` in your ini file
- Have `./bin/less` running in a terminal all the time

Answer (score 5):

Beware that `apt-get install nodejs` installs `nodejs` and NOT `node` in `/usr/bin`, at least in Ubuntu 12.10 (I didn't check in other distributions). This throws errors since both `ckan/bin/less` as well as `ckan/node_modules/less/bin/lessc` are calling  `node`. So either create a softlink in /usr/bin or modify the scripts (`#!/usr/bin/env nodejs`).

Comment: Good tip @hbunke. I didn't have to do this in Ubuntu 12.04. But you're right, it seems in 12.10 `/usr/bin/node` has become `/usr/bin/nodejs` ([Ubuntu 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/nodejs/filelist), [Ubuntu 12.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/nodejs/filelist)).

Answer (score 4):

I got few errors while installing the packages. Following is the solution (according to [official CKAN docs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html?highlight=debug#attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-css-main-debug-css)) for impatient:

`cp /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/public/base/css/main.css /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/public/base/css/main.debug.css`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an ubuntu 12.04 and experiencing some problems with this

Was getting this error after following Sean's answers and running

`npm install less nodewatch`

and got this error:

```
(default)root@ckan:/# npm install less nodewatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nodewatch
npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: less
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "less" "nodewatch"
npm ERR! cwd /
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: less
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Found another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/installing-from-npm-fails) that explains this and offers the solution to execute

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

However after running the above command I am getting this error:

```
(default)root@ckan:/# npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
(default)root@ckan:/# npm install less nodewatch
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/nodewatch
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/less/-/less-1.6.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/nodewatch
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/nodewatch/-/nodewatch-0.3.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/less/-/less-1.6.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/nodewatch/-/nodewatch-0.3.1.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.33.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.33.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.11.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
npm WARN optional dependency failed, continuing clean-css@2.0.x
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.11.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/-/source-map-0.1.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/-/source-map-0.1.3.tgz
npm ERR! error installing less@1.6.3
npm ERR! error rolling back less@1.6.3 Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/node_modules/less'

npm ERR! Unsupported
npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: request@2.33.0
npm ERR! Required: ["node >= 0.8.0"]
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.1.4","node":"0.6.12"}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "less" "nodewatch"
npm ERR! cwd /
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! message Unsupported
npm ERR! errno {}
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/requirejs/0.26.0
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Seems like the version are incompatible or could this be the problem with node and node.js?

Cheers,
Shao

Comment: The error was due to an old version of node installed using apt-get. To solve this, I followed the instructions from [here](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nodejs/node-js-npm-install-ubuntu/) and following the official ckan documentation [here](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.0.2/frontend-development.html) to install it in the correct directory.