# CKAN error: No module name css/foundation.css

Tags: ubuntu, ckan

I change bootstrap to foundation zurb. I already install nodejs for Frontend development guidelines (http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/contributing/frontend/index.html). I already execute the ./bin/less --production command. My development environment works ok but my ckan_default.error.log gives me an error "No module name css/foundation.css" every time I try to access my production at port 8080.

Any idea? - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following previous answer, [object has no attribute 'css/main.debug.css'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480800/ckan-development-install-issue-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute), I got around a similar error with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get update
sudo npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo npm install less nodewatch
```