# Problems installing phoneGap on Terminal

Tags: cordova

Hey I'm following the instructions of phoneGap and while using the following command in terminal

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

I get the following errors

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
```

and

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-0.6.0-1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/node-static/-/node-static-0.7.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova/-/cordova-3.1.0-0.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap-build/-/phonegap-build-0.8.4.tgz
```

and

```
npm ERR! network socket hang up
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/kaldenficklin
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kaldenficklin/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I downloaded node.js before hand like instructed to. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong and how to fix it??

Comment: A colleague is having the same issue. It seems likely that there are issues on NPM registry's side.

Comment: We're also seeing the issue - wonder if there any way to alert NPM Registry maintainers?

Comment: Yeah I'm also having an issue installing pretty much anything through NPM right now, and by the looks of their site it's currently down.

Comment: same for me, bunch of error parsing json and the like

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Been having it all day.

Comment: anyone able to solve ? I'm having the same problem since yesterday.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13119867/1955071, please use following command and then install phonegap,

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Afterwards, in case you get this error "Error: No compatible version found: phonegap" then add force flag to install it,

```
sudo npm install -gf phonegap
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if we have the same problem, but I update the node.js and phonegap have installed without problem, try it!