# Why does npm install say I have unmet dependencies?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm

I have a node package. When I run `npm install` from the package root, it installs a bunch of things, but then prints several error messages that look like this:

> npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/seanmackesey/google_drive/code/explore/generator/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob requires graceful-fs@'~1.2.0' but will load

I must be confused about what exactly `npm install` does. If it detects a dependency, shouldn't it install it? Under what conditions does it give me error messages like this, and how can I resolve the dependencies?

Answer (score 415, accepted):

I believe it is because the dependency resolution is a bit broken, see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1341#issuecomment-20634338

Following are the possible solution :

1. Manually need to install the top-level modules, containing unmet dependencies:
   `npm install findup-sync@0.1.2`
2. Re-structure your package.json. Place all the high-level modules (serves as a dependency for others modules) at the bottom.
3. Re-run the `npm install` command.

The problem could be caused by npm's failure to download all the package due to timed-out or something else.

Note: You can also install the failed packages manually as well using `npm install findup-sync@0.1.2`.

Before running `npm install`,  performing the following steps may help:

- remove node_modules using `rm -rf node_modules/`
- run `npm cache clean`

Why 'removing node_modules' sometimes is necessary? 
When a nested module fails to install during `npm install`, subsequent `npm install` won't detect those missing nested dependencies.

If that's the case, sometimes it's sufficient to remove the top-level dependency of those missing nested modules, and running `npm install` again. See

Comment: geon raises another good point, if an `npm install` doesn't finish you'll get the same result. `npm` has been a bit flakey as of late, so sometimes modules simply fail to download, but re-running `npm install` in these case will sometimes fix itself.

Comment: Removing the node modules and cleaning the cache made it work for me.

Comment: removing 'node_modules', running 'npm cache clean', and then running 'npm install' fixed my issue. I had to run 'npm_install' three times, until i got all dependencies loaded without errors.

Comment: if `npm cache clean` doesn't work for access reasons, try `sudo npm cache clean`.

Comment: @Soroush blindly just adding sudo to things that don't work right doesn't magically fix them, just means you don't know whats going on.

Comment: Go for the first suggestion: directly installing the missing module. Someone on NPM spent the time correctly implementing the error message. Do what it says.

Comment: why does ever other "solution" for npm include rm r node_modules? and why is it that this is really the only option in most of the cases? that's not quite how I figure a package manager should work like

Comment: Use rm -r node_modules NOT rm -rf node_modules

Comment: I have deleted the node_modules, I have cleaned the cache and I have installed one by one all unmet dependencies and works, thank you very much.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me after structuring the `package.json`, such that the top-level modules were listed down the order. In my case i was having trouble with `react-interpolate-component` and `react-translate-component` requiring a peer of `react@^15.5.4r` after I upgraded to  `react@16.2.0`. Thanks for the help. I also did a `cache clean`  before this.

Comment: i had the problem of having unmet dependencies showing up in `npm list`, even after uninstalling nodejs package and removing all node related folders. I was able to resolve those warnings using the command `npm update`.

Answer (score 89):

It happened to me when the WIFI went down during an `npm install`. Removing `node_modules` and re-running `npm install` fixed it.

Comment: and try `npm cache clean`.

Comment: Reinstalling node probably isn't necessary, but between doing that, `npm cache clean` and removing `node_modules`, this advice worked for me.

Comment: @RichLitt, Yeah doing `npm cache clean` was not enough for me, I had to remove the `node_modules` as well to get it to work after the networked failed during the "install".

Comment: I'm confused as to which `node_modules` directory to remove? I have a similar problem with the error `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/readdir-scoped-modules requires graceful-fs@'^4.1.2'`

Comment: @wuliwong The top level one.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && nvm use && npm i`

Comment: Use rm -r node_modules NOT rm -rf node_modules to remove node_modules

Answer (score 33):

I fixed the issue by using these command lines

- `$ rm -rf node_modules/`
- `$ sudo npm update -g npm`
- `$ npm install`

It's done!

Comment: After running sudo npm update -g npm, my npm was rendered useless, any attempt to install anything results in "npm ERR! Cannot find module 'read-package-json'"
im going to have to down vote this

Comment: It worked for me and for other people, maybe you have an other problem.
Try installing the module read-package-json globally
`sudo npm install -g read-package-json`
Or reinstall your npm

Comment: caveat: you shouldn't use sudo with `npm`, it's suggested instead to change the permissions or ownership of the directory npm wants to write too.

Comment: might want to add "npm cache clean" in there too

Comment: I shared my experience, I did not know that I should be expert to share it, it's just a npm modules directory, it's not a `sudo rm -vrfr /` If you have an explanation it would be good to complete the answer and see your contribution or juste upvote the best answer it'll be great

Comment: Do not use `sudo` with npm

Comment: Use rm -r node_modules NOT rm -rf node_modules

Comment: @BinaryJoe01 can you explain why please ?

Comment: @Amine HADDAD because **rm -rf node_modules** was not working for me and *after over an hour of searching* I found **rm -r node_modules** to work.  I am on Windows 10.  Also, make sure you *run node as adminstrator.*

Answer (score 12):

Upgrading NPM to the latest version can greatly help with this. dule's answer above is right to say that dependency management is a bit broken, but it seems that this is mainly for older versions of npm.

The command `npm list` gives you a list of all installed `node_modules`. When I upgraded from version 1.4.2 to version 2.7.4, many modules that were previously flagged with `WARN unmet dependency` were no longer noted as such.

To update npm, you should type `npm install -g npm` on MacOSX or Linux.  On Windows, I found that re-downloading and re-running the nodejs installer was a more effective way to update npm.

Comment: I had the same problem with the npm version distributed in CentOS 7 repos. I installed latest npm version from node.js, and the problem disappeared, so I think your right,  it can be an issue with an old version.

Answer (score 11):

The above answers didn't help me fully even after deleteting `node_modules` directory.

Below command helped me finally:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Note that this pulls node modules over an insecure HTTP connection.

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13119867/4082503

Comment: This helped me as well as my host was redirecting traffic.

Comment: @Dejel did you try the other answers also. You may have to run `npm install` multiple times and/or manually install some node packages one by one.

Answer (score 7):

For every `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY`, for ex. `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-rc.2`, install that dependency with `npm install --save rxjs@5.0.0-rc.2` until you don't have any more `UNMET DEPENDENCIES`.

Good Luck.

Comment: Leaves me with the same errors including a new one: `ERR! code 1`

Comment: @WouterVanherck can you please try `rm -rf node_modules`, then `npm cache clean` and `npm install`.  If it still doesn't work, I suggest you to again `rm -rf node_modules`, then `npm i -g yarn` and then `yarn install`. [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) is quite good to manage `node_modules`.  Good Luck.

Comment: Yes, is what ```peerDependencies``` is for. To push you to a conscious choice of the version.

Answer (score 6):

I run `npm list` and installed all the packages listed as UNMET DEPENDENCY

For instance:

`├── UNMET DEPENDENCY css-loader@^0.23.1` 
`npm install css-loader@^0.23.1`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue while I was installing the React Native CLI. I wasn't sure which `/node_modules` directory I was supposed to remove after reading the answers here. I eventually just ran

`npm update -g`

and was able to install the package after that.

Answer (score 2):

This solved it for me:

1. Correct the version numbers in `package.json`, according to the errors;
2. Remove `node_modules` (`rm -rf node_modules`);
3. Rerun `npm install`.

Repeat these steps until there are no more errors.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing in the similar vein, I would add one other step.

Note that on npm version > 1.4.9, 'npm install' does install devDependencies. First try removing existing modules and cache:

```
remove node_modules $ rm -rf node_modules/
run $ npm cache clean
```

Then try:

```
npm install --dev
npm update --dev
```

This at least will resolve the recursive dependency resolution.

Comment: what is the --dev flag for?

Answer (score 1):

--dev installing devDependencies recursively (and its run forever..)
how it can help to resolve the version differences?

You can try remove the node_moduls folder, then clean the npm cache and then run 'npm i' again

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to work on an automated deployment system that runs `npm install`, so a lot of these solutions wouldn't work for me in an automated fasion. I wasn't in a position to go deleting/re-creating `node_modules/` nor could I easily change Node.js versions.

So I ended up running `npm shrinkwrap` - adding the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file to my deployment bundle, and running installs from there. That fixed the problem for me; with the shrinkwrap file as a 'helper', npm seemed to be able to find the right packages and get them installed for me. (Shrinkwrap has other features as well, but this was what I needed it for in this particular case).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when I was installing react packages and this worked for me:
     `npm install --save <package causing this error>`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the update of npm solved it.

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` will install all the packages from `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, but might ignore packages in `package.json`, if they're not preset in the former.

If you're project has a `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, make sure you run `npm shrinkwrap` to regenerate it, each time you add add/remove/change `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Take care about your angular version, if you work under angular 2.x.x so maybe you need to upgrade to angular 4.x.x

Some dependencies needs angular 4

[Here is a tutorial for how to install angular 4 or update your project.](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/55/How-to-Install-an-Angular-4-App)

Answer (score 0):

**Updating to 4.0.0**

Updating to 4 is as easy as updating your Angular dependencies to the latest version, and double checking if you want animations. This will work for most use cases.

On Linux/Mac:

```
npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest typescript@latest --save
```

On Windows:

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```

Then run whatever ng serve or npm start command you normally use, and everything should work.

If you rely on Animations, import the new `BrowserAnimationsModule` from `@angular/platform-browser/animations` in your root `NgModule`. Without this, your code will compile and run, but animations will trigger an error. Imports from `@angular/core` were deprecated, use imports from the new package

```
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';.
```