# How to undo npm update?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a way to undo the command `npm update`? I ran the command and now I have a bunch of unmet dependencies and some errors.

I'm trying to manually reinstall and fix all the errors but does anyone know how to essentially revert an `npm update`?

Comment: Related: [Why does npm install say I have unmet dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks I actually ended up doing the solution suggested in that question. Wish I saw it sooner.

Comment: I’m horrified at the implication that you aren’t using version control (like `git`). Trust me, you want this.

Comment: @AlanH. yeah when I originally posted this answer, I wasn't super familiar with how npm worked internally. [The documentation is a lot clearer now](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update). Also before `npm@5.0.0` when npm didn't save the dependency changes to your package.json, it wasn't as obvious what was changing

Comment: Got it  Consider Yarn, too. It’s a better-designed and more reliable `npm` in our experience.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can restore your `package.json` file to its previous state (hopefully you still have that, or at least remember what you had changed), and then do another `npm update`.

[UPDATE]

However, in general, this technique does not guarantee that your entire dependency tree will be restored to its exact former state (since the `package.json` files in a dependency tree often loosely specify dependency versions).

If you need to ensure that your package's dependency tree can be restored exactly, you have to use something like [npm shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) to "lock down" the dependency versions (*before* you publish the package).

Comment: Wouldn't this simply be redoing the `npm update` that I first did? I wanted to revert back to my original state, not `npm update` again.

Comment: `npm update` enforces your node package's dependencies, exactly as specified in your `package.json` (including the versions of the dependencies). It does not simply update everything to the latest version.

Comment: Ah I see thank you for the clarification. Accepting your answer.

Comment: What do you do if your `package.json` has tilde or caret versions and a dependency update (non-major) breaks your build? How do you revert to the exact versions you had installed before the update?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Unfortunately, there is probably nothing you can do at this point to easily fix this issue. Going forward, you may want to use `npm shrinkwrap` to avoid this issue.

Comment: In my experience, `rm -rf node_modules && npm update` does the trick nicely. So well in fact I am considering putting it in my build script. If it was not for the ~10s it adds to my build and the fact that internet access would become mandatory to build.

Answer (score 18):

Do this:

```
git log
```

then Copy the latest latest key. This will let you checkout your latest commit.

```
git checkout "your-key" package.json
git checkout "your-key" package-lock.json
```

without the `"` quotes

*(package-lock.json is really necessary, but I like to do et anyway - "Just to make sure...")*

you can do a

```
git status
```

to make sure that your `package.json` and `package.lock`

You can also do the

```
rm -rf node_modules/
```

which will delete node_modules folder

```
npm install
```

Comment: if you want the latest commit you can do `HEAD` or if you've already committed changes just do `HEAD~1` to get the commit before. Thanks for the follow up answer though :) I'm sure some people will appreciate it

Comment: I don't know whether it makes any difference but at the time of writing `npm install` seems to downgrade correctly even if you don't wipe out `node_modules`.

Answer (score 3):

All I did was to do "rm -rf node_modules" to uninstall the updated node_modules and then "npm install" to reinstall them; my package.json hadn't change when I did npm update which caused all the havoc.  So by deleting and reinstalling node_modules I'm gladly back in business.

Comment: But `npm update` does write to *package.json*... Probably in earlier versions it would not but right now I see my *package.json* being updated everytime I update.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout "your-key" package.json
git checkout "your-key" package-lock.json
```

without the " quotes

(`package-lock.json` isn't really necessary, but I like to do it anyway - "Just to make sure...")

You can do a

```
git status
```

Comment: I think the package-lock.json IS necessary to get the exact same versions back.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned to use different branches in git, even when working solo.

So when I recently screwed up my npm, I could just:

git stash (stashes recent changes)
git switch main (switches back to main branch)
npm update (re-aligns npm packages with package.json file)

The key is to get back to the file, and npm update. Or else pull the file out of github, and replace yours, and then npm update.

Comment: But I've just read of npm shrinkwrap above, so I'm going to explore that option for future!