# change package-lock.json package back to original repo version

Tags: git, npm

I'm working on a git pull request for Mocha.

I'm running into an error related to my package-lock.json file in where I accidentally updated the package ansi-regex from 2.1.1 to 3.0.0

I'm now having issues getting this version back to it's original, which was requested by the repo owners.

The major issue I am encountering is that this npm package only exists within package-lock

```
 "ansi-regex": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-7QMXwyIGT3lGbAKWa922Bas32Zg="
    },
```

it doesn't exist inside the main package.json file.

Through research, I've found that it's not suggested to delete the package-lock file and regenerate it with npm i because that could introduce even more changes.

I've also tried the command:

```
git checkout --theirs package-lock.json
git add package-lock.json
```

But the version remains 3.0.0

I've also tried to run a

```
npm uninstall --save ansi-regex@3.0.0 -package-lock.json
```

To manually remove the file, but the command completes without removing any packages.

I'm not sure how to get this version back to the one setup by the repo owners and could really use some help figuring out next steps.

Thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to find the ID of a commit before the one where you modified `package-lock.json`, and restore the content of `package-lock.json` from that commit.

---

Using the command line (open `git-bash` for example) :

- You can view the list of commits that modified `package-lock.json` using :

  ```
  git log package-lock.json
  ```
- You can set `package-lock.json` back to its version in commit `[ID]` using :

  ```
  git checkout [ID] -- package-lock.json
  ```

You can do the same actions from a graphical client, just be sure to select the file from the past commit and checkout only that file, rather than checkout the whole commit.

Comment: I meant to come back and answer this question myself. 
After I posted this I went and researched more and found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954247/how-to-undo-npm-update


 Where they said something similar to what you suggested, so I'll make this as correct incase someone comes searching for this in the future

Thank you for the detailed response!

Comment: Just for the sake of clarification, with [ID] you mean hash, right?

Comment: @dawn [ID] = commit id.

Comment: @dawn: yes, the `sha` of target commit (note: if you have a tag or a branch or any name that points to this commit, you can also use that tag/branch/name)

Answer (score 1):

Easier way is to just open the source project and switch to the branch with which you will be comparing your branch. (Say 'main').
Then, just copy the whole content of package-lock.json and paste it in your branch.

Answer (score -1):

git checkout -- package-lock.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).