# How to know the previous version of an installed npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I wish to know version of package before updating the package using npm. I have updated a package to latest version and have some compatibility issues. what command should I use to know last version of installed package before update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo npm update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954247/how-to-undo-npm-update)

Answer (score 0):

NPM doesn’t provide such a command.

If you want to track your changes, you need to use a version control system such as Git.