# npm WARN unmet dependency when Installing Gulp on Max OS X Yosemite

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, gulp, ionic-framework

I have a series of problems with node, ruby and gem for installing compass and sass. So I removed node and ruby and re-installed them (node v0.12) using Mac OS X package installer from node website.

Now I have problem with installing gulp:

```
sudo npm install  -g gulp
/usr/local/bin/gulp -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/init-package-json requires   glob@'^5.0.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.6
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/rimraf requires glob@'^4.4.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.6
gulp@3.8.11 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp
├── pretty-hrtime@0.2.2
├── interpret@0.3.10
├── deprecated@0.0.1
├── archy@1.0.0
├── minimist@1.1.1
├── semver@4.3.3
├── v8flags@2.0.3 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── tildify@1.0.0 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── orchestrator@0.3.7 (stream-consume@0.1.0, sequencify@0.0.7, end-of-stream@0.1.5)
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
├── liftoff@2.0.3 (extend@2.0.0, flagged-respawn@0.3.1, resolve@1.1.6, findup-sync@0.2.1)
├── gulp-util@3.0.4 (array-differ@1.0.0, object-assign@2.0.0, beeper@1.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.2, lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, chalk@1.0.0, vinyl@0.4.6, through2@0.6.3, multipipe@0.1.2, lodash.template@3.4.0, dateformat@1.0.11)
└── vinyl-fs@0.3.13 (graceful-fs@3.0.6, mkdirp@0.5.0, strip-bom@1.0.0, vinyl@0.4.6, defaults@1.0.2, through2@0.6.3, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6)
```

I don't have any idea!

Comment: The biggest problem is that you're installing stuff using `sudo`. It'll install stuff to the sudo users home directory instead of your own. Reinstall everything without using sudo and you'll most likely be fine. Otherwise, reinstall the specific modules that you have, most likely you've installed them as global dependencies instead of local to your project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does npm install say I have unmet dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: First I always try with no sudo but I got EACCESS error: npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/Users/hassan/.npm/_locks/gulp-709d00e5d169ceb3.lock'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)

Comment: For the su stuff, check out https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions