# Why does npm list -g lead to npm ERR! missing error?

Tags: node.js, npm

npm returns the following message after using `npm list -g`

> ```
> npm ERR! missing: atom-package-manager@*, required by undefined@undefined
> npm ERR! missing: opal-npm-wrapper@git://github.com/anthonny/opal-npm-wrapper.git#0.1.1, required by asciidoctor.js@1.5.2
> npm ERR! missing: xmlhttprequest@~1.6.0, required by asciidoctor.js@1.5.2
> ```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: what was the output of the `npm install`? Did it report any missing optional dependencies?

Answer (score 16):

I know this an old question but I've been strugging with a similar issue and figure I'd at least add what worked for me...

**Problem**

Running `npm list -g` lists all packages as expected and then throws a variety of errors including the missing errors, as mentioned above, and, for me at least, a bunch of invalid and extraneous errors such as this:

```
extraneous: aws-sign2@0.5.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/aws-sign2
```

I tried a bunch of solutions including `npm upgrade`, `npm prune`, as well as installing missing packages, which for me was semver:

```
missing: semver@2 || 3, required by normalize-package-data@1.0.1
```

I'm still not sure of the exact cause for these errors, though I believe this happened when I upgraded to 3.3.6.

**Solution**

After some headache I ran:

```
npm update -g --verbose
```

which upgraded me from v3.3.6 to v3.5.3 and got rid of all the errors. Note that the `--verbose` is not necessary but helpful to see what exactly is happening. Now my `npm list -g` returns a clean output:

```
/usr/local/lib
├── npm@3.5.3
└── semver@2.3.2
```

Hope this helps someone, please comment if I've stated any inaccuracies or if there's something I can add here.

Comment: A downvote with no comment? Please elaborate... if this answer is incorrect  or causes issues I'm happy to delete).

Comment: `npm update -g --verbose` didn't help. `npm cache clean --force` didn't help either. In my case, one of CLI apps was symlinked and it's from Lerna local folder so all deps were symlinked and deemed missing by npm. I reinstalled public version of it, same package but it's like phantom error which persists. Reported ERR dependencies are in place. It's not solved...

Answer (score 7):

For anyone having the same problem, try to run:

```
npm dedupe
```

for more info about `npm dedupe` please refer to the documentation.
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe.html

Answer (score 2):

Remove `package-lock.json` in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: It'd be a huge help to readers if you explained why this is the right answer, and how you worked out that it was the problem.

Comment: The file `/usr/local/lib/package-lock.json` does not exist - though, the folder exists and contains the subfolder `node_modules`.

Comment: The `package.lock.json` stamps exact versions into your repo. By removing it and re-running you allow npm to go and rebuild all the dependencies from scratch and to resolve any conflicts as part of this.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a global package named asciidoctor.js that is installed before its dependency packages are installed. I ran into the same problem today: some of my global package has "UNMET DEP" in its tree structure(run npm list -g to see the full depth of each global package), meaning its subdependencies are missing.

I solved by reinstalling each global package. If you had this problem on Arch Linux, 
first check this post: [I have unmet dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies)

I had this problem surfaced after I `sudo pacman -Syu` and I have a bunch of ERROR missing `semver` and `node-pyg`.

As a side note, under Arch Linux `node-pyg` and `semver` are installed as dependencies before `npm` is installed through `pacman`(rather than through `npm`), and I guess the order these two are installed or updated matters. Probably under other OS or linux distros, these two packages are not listed in the repository.