# NPM update -g lot of warnings but succeeds

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

Recently I started messing around with NPM packages... first I had some problems with dependencies and got great help here. Now I'm having issues when I want to update the CLI application... If I uninstall en do install everything works smoothly, when I do **npm update -g** however, it fails.

This is the logging I get (warning long file):

```
npm update -g wmg
-
> dtrace-provider@0.4.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/wmg/node_modules/restify/node_modules/dtrace-provider
> node scripts/install.js

/usr/local/bin/wmg -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/wmg/wmg.js
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tar-fs/node_modules/tar-stream/node_modules/bl']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tar-fs/node_modules/tar-stream/node_modules/bl' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inherits']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inherits' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tar-fs/node_modules/tar-stream/node_modules/readable-stream']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tar-fs/node_modules/tar-stream/node_modules/readable-stream' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tar-fs/node_modules/tar-stream/node_modules/end-of-stream']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tar-fs/node_modules/tar-stream/node_modules/end-of-stream' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/columnify/node_modules/wcwidth.js/node_modules/underscore']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/columnify/node_modules/wcwidth.js/node_modules/underscore' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/boom']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/boom' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/cryptiles']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/cryptiles' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/hoek']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/hoek' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/sntp']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/sntp' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/asn1']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/asn1' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/assert-plus']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/assert-plus' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/ctype']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/ctype' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmconf/node_modules/config-chain/node_modules/proto-list']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmconf/node_modules/config-chain/node_modules/proto-list' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/node_modules/punycode']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/node_modules/punycode' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/columnify/node_modules/strip-ansi/node_modules/ansi-regex']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/columnify/node_modules/strip-ansi/node_modules/ansi-regex' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/entities']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/entities' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/CSSselect']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/CSSselect' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/underscore']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/underscore' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/htmlparser2']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/htmlparser2' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils/node_modules/lodash']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils/node_modules/lodash' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils/node_modules/isbinaryfile']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils/node_modules/isbinaryfile' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils/node_modules/minimatch']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils/node_modules/minimatch' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/mute-stream']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/mute-stream' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inherits']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inherits' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/readline2']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/readline2' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/through']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/through' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/forever-agent']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/forever-agent' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/aws-sign2']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/aws-sign2' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/oauth-sign']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/oauth-sign' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/qs']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/qs' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/json-stringify-safe']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/json-stringify-safe' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/CSSselect/node_modules/CSSwhat']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/CSSselect/node_modules/CSSwhat' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/each-async']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/each-async' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/get-stdin']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/get-stdin' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/get-urls']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/get-urls' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/nopt']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/nopt' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/through2']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/through2' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/request']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/request' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/CSSselect/node_modules/domutils']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/CSSselect/node_modules/domutils' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/dom-serializer/node_modules/domelementtype']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/dom-serializer/node_modules/domelementtype' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/lru-cache']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/lru-cache' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/each-async']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/each-async' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/archive-type']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/archive-type' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/object-assign']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/object-assign' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/fs-extra']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/fs-extra' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils/node_modules/glob']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils/node_modules/glob' }
glob error { [Error: EMFILE, readdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/debug/node_modules/ms']
  errno: 20,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/debug/node_modules/ms' }
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download requires request@'^2.34.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.30.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils requires lodash@'~2.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.4.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils requires isbinaryfile@'~0.1.9' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/isbinaryfile,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.2
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils requires glob@'~3.2.6' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.6
wmg@0.0.16 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/wmg
├── underscore@1.8.3
├── prompt@0.2.14 (pkginfo@0.3.0, revalidator@0.1.8, read@1.0.6, winston@0.8.3, utile@0.2.1)
└── restify@3.0.3 (assert-plus@0.1.5, escape-regexp-component@1.0.2, tunnel-agent@0.4.1, keep-alive-agent@0.0.1, deep-equal@1.0.0, negotiator@0.5.3, lru-cache@2.6.5, mime@1.3.4, formidable@1.0.17, node-uuid@1.4.3, qs@2.4.2, semver@4.3.6, spdy@1.32.0, once@1.3.2, backoff@2.4.1, verror@1.6.0, csv@0.4.5, http-signature@0.10.1, bunyan@1.3.4, dtrace-provider@0.4.0)
```

Anyone that has seen something like this before?

Answer (score 1):

The `EMFILE error` basically means that too many files are being opened in parallel. That makes sense because NPM is opening all the files it is throwing errors on (and there are clearly plenty).

Since these are just warnings I don't think you need to worry because as far as I know you can not edit how many files NPM works on at once.

With that being said, if you do think that you would like to get to the bottom of the warnings I would suggest [graceful-fs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs) which might be able to help.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but this isn't my application running... this is when I'm updating my package... so this is the output of **npm -g update wmg** so my application isn't actually running...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies)?

Comment: Now I have ;-) ... but I "fixed" this just by adding some stuff in the .profile... allowing my laptop to get some more files open... I had too many NPM packages apparently... which f*cked up my updates. Wasn't related to my own package

Comment: Okay great, I'm glad everything works now. If my answer helped don't forget to click the green check to accept the answer :)