# NPM operations slow on Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, browserify

I'm using NPM as my package manager for React development. Everything is fine on my Mac locally (`npm install` takes a few seconds to a minute, builds using browserify/uglify take approximately 20s), but the same operations take 3-5 times longer on the server.

Assuming that the server (a small Rackspace Ubuntu instance) is at least as powerful as my ageing MacBook, what could the problem be? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a problem of bandwidth?

Comment: It's not bandwidth – it's slow with both `npm install` (which does need bandwidth) and a browserify build (which doesn't).

Comment: Ok. Which version of NPM are you using?

Comment: Could you look at the output of `npm install -ddd` on both platforms? There might be some issue there.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for... but:

- The one locally runs in about 5s, the one on the server about 8s, both with pauses on `npm verb validateInstall loading .../package.json for validation`
- The one on the server returns `npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/climbrs/js/react-app/node_modules/webpack requires uglify-js@'~2.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/climbrs/js/react-app/node_modules/uglify-js,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.4.24`

Thanks!

Comment: So only on the server you get `npm WARN unmet dependency`? You might want to look at this answer then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies