# Cant install ionic framework - Dependency error

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install ionic framework on my Ubuntu 14.04 Linux system. I already installed the nodejs,npm,cordova. I use the command 'npm install -g ionic' in my terminal and everytime I get the following error

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/dineshadhithya/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/connect/node_modules/finalhandler requires debug@'1.0.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/dineshadhithya/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/request/node_modules/    form-data requires combined-stream@'~0.0.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
ionic@1.7.14 node_modules/ionic
```

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo npm install -g ionic`? Also, are you sure `Ionic`is not installed because these are just warnings

Comment: Yes, that didn't work too

Comment: After the commanf 'sudo npm install -g ionic', I checked if Ionic is correctly installed, I used 'ionic  --version' command, it didn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to have solved the problem for many: [Why does npm install say I have unmet dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies)

- remove `node_modules` using `rm -rf node_modules/`
- run `npm cache clean`

Comment: Does it take long time for ionic to get installed?? Because the terminal seems to have struck in the middle of the process.

Comment: Normally it shouldn't. Are you installing behind a proxy?