# npm deprecated lodash@1.0.2 and npm deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3 version issue for npm install?

Tags: npm, angular, npm-install

Previously I am getting unmet dependecy so for that I tried
[Why does npm install say I have unmet dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies) but now getting 
npm deprecated lodash@1.0.2 and npm deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3 version issue for npm install

[image]

Comment: what nodejs version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands in your command line:

```
npm install lodash
npm install graceful-fs
```