# Ionic 2 Alert Component property create does not exist on type Alert

Tags: components, alert, ionic2

I've import `Alert Component` in my `ionic 2` project like this :

```
import {Alert } from 'ionic-angular';
```

**Usage:**

```
let alert = this.alert.create({
    title: 'New Friend!',
    subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
alert.present();
```

**But my error is :** `Property create does not exist on type Alert.`

**Ionic Info :**

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 1.2.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.37
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.12.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```

**how can i solve it ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using pieces of new pattern for creating alerts, but you have Ionic Framework 10, where things are done a bit differently.

You should **inject AlertController into constructor**. Also, when importing **Alert, it has new name** - *AlertController*.

More on new way of [creating overlays (incluiding alerts) at official Ionic 2 blog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

edit: If you want to update to Beta 11, just run:

```
npm install --save --save-exact ionic-angular @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4 @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.4 @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.4 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.4 @angular/forms rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 zone.js@0.6.12
```

I had troubles updating, got *npm WARN unmet dependency*, so I did reinstall npm in my Ionic directory:

1. remove node_modules using *rm -rf node_modules/*
2. run *npm cache clean*
3. run mentioned npm install command again

You also need to fix other changes in Beta 11, as mentioned at [Beta 11 changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). More on [failed npm install due to unmet dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies) at SO.

Comment: And for the beta 10 implementation you call `create` on the Alert class... `let alert = Alert.create({ options })` and present it with the NavController `this.navCtrl.present(alert);`

Comment: ok thanks for your response but how can i update the Ionic 2 in the existing project?

Comment: @mahmoudismail Beta 11 installation added in answer

Comment: @mahmoudismail: you can change it in package.json on following line: "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-beta.11" and then delete node_modules and run "npm install". And then don't forget look on steps to upgrade to beta 11: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade-to-beta-11

Comment: "inject AlertController into constructor" was the issue, Thank you