# AlertController ionic 2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: ionic2

I tried to do validation when exiting the app, But I encountered an error when using  AlertController ionic 2: , I follow the instructions at https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/

Sorry, I'm not good at English

My bug:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
at Object.MyApp.exit [as fn] (main.js:143575)
at Platform.runBackButtonAction (main.js:2347)
at main.js:2022
at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (main.js:54953)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (main.js:1388)
at SafeSubscriber.next (main.js:1337)
at Subscriber._next (main.js:1290)
at Subscriber.next (main.js:1254)
at EventEmitter.Subject.next (main.js:7763)
at EventEmitter.emit (main.js:54927)
at main.js:104021
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvoke (main.js:38895)
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at e.run (polyfills.js:3)
```

My code app.component.ts:

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991446/ionic-2-alert-component-property-create-does-not-exist-on-type-alert

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 exit(){
   this.alertCtrl.create({
     title :'' , 
     subTitle:'',
     buttons:['']
   }).then(alertEt =>{
    alertEt.present();
   }) 
}
```