# react native app cannot fetch bundle

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Although `npm start` or `react-native start` is running 
app gives this error:

[image]

When I searched I tried `npm install` it gives this error:

[image]

How to fix this?

It seems like missing a dependency of the react native project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install the dependency packages

```
npm install --force react@15.3.1
```

instead of

```
npm install react@15.3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The prompt show very clear,Unable to connect your device to the packager sever.

If your device and your computer under the same wi-fi,You can according to the last attempt to modify the connection attributes of your device.

Comment: i understand your suggestion, i set the correct ip address for the debug server host & port also. But it was an error of react version. There was unmet dependencies. How I solved is by executing  "npm install --force react@15.3.1"

Comment: This problem can try under reference [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies)