# Ionic 2 Final + AngularFire2 : UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12

Tags: node.js, ionic2, angularfire2

On Windows 10 with nodejs 7.5.0, after installing the ionic 2 final version there is a peer dependency error (rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12) when installing angularfire2.

Tried on Linux but the result was the same.

```
ionic -v
2.2.1
npm install angularfire2 --save
ionic-hello-world@ D:\nodejs\unRated
+-- angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.7
-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.7 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
```

Anyone with the same issue on the final ionic 2 release?

Comment: have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install AngularFire 2.0.0-beta.6 to make it working.

```js
npm install firebase@3.3.0 angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.6
```

Check this blog for more information https://chriztalk.com/ionic-2-and-firebase/