# Typescript with Angular2 - Targeting ES5 yields errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm using `npm -v =>3.10.10` and I want to run a new project (empty one) of Angular2.

If I write

`npm isntall angular2 --save`

I get this :

[image]

But after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765400/859154) which states :

> You may need to manually install top-level modules that have unmet
>   dependencies:

— I did this:

- `npm isntall es6-shim@^0.35.0 --save`
- `npm isntall reflect-metadata@0.1.2 --save`
- `npm isntall rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 --save`
- `npm isntall  zone.js@^0.6.12 --save`

So now I have this :

[image]

So now `package.json` looks like :

```
{
  "name": "AngularJS2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Ray Villalobos",
  "description": "...",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/planetoftheweb/angular2.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp-webserver": "^0.9.1"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.21",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
}
```

And `tsconfig.json` looks like :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
   "node_modules"

  ]
}
```

Now I run `gulp` in `cmd` and the site is up and running fine ( [*this is the gulpFile.js file*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egQE1.jpg)) :

But looking at the cmd  - [**I see many warnings**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6lv6.jpg) :

```
C:\Users\sff\Desktop\1>gulp [11:39:33] Using gulpfile
~\Desktop\1\gulpfile.js [11:39:33] Starting 'copylibs'... [11:39:33]
Starting 'typescript'... [11:39:33] Starting 'watch'... [11:39:33]
Finished 'watch' after 22 ms [11:39:33] Starting 'webserver'...
[11:39:33] Webserver started at http://localhost:8000 [11:39:33]
Finished 'webserver' after 8.84 ms
C:/Users/sff/Desktop/1/node_modules/angular2/platform/browser.d.ts(78,90):
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/Users/sff/Desktop/1/node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(38,88):
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/Users/sff/Desktop/1/node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(92,42):
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/Users/sff/Desktop/1/node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(151,33):
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/Users/sff/Desktop/1/node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(23,15):
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/Users/sff/Desktop/1/node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(25,16):
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/Users/sff/Desktop/1/node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(103,123):
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/Users/sff/Desktop/1/node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(103,165):
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
```

**However - I've already found the solution** :

- I've installed `npm install @types/core-js --save-dev`

And

Changed the content of  `tsconfig.json` from :

`"target": "es5"` ---to ---> `"target": "es6"`

Now it looks good:

[image]

**Question**

The errors were becuase `Map`, `Set` and `Promise` are `ES6` features.
-Which causes the compiler the use the normal `es5 lib.d.ts` which lacks the definitions for the above types.

But now things won't work as they should becuase not all browsers supports this.

- Is this the right way of fixing the warnings? Also - How can I "ES5'y" my code ?

PS

Other solution states that changing the TS file to :

```
 "target": "es5",
 "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
```

Should work. But it's not. still same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to download a deprecated version of angular2 :

use @angular/cli because everything (`tsconfig`, `@types/` and `shims`) is configured for you  :

```
npm install @angular/cli -g 

ng new myApp

cd myApp

ng serve
```