# "unmet peer dependency joi@* " error during installation of the express-validation module

Tags: node.js, validation, express

In express JS During the course of dynamic routing I want to verify the parameters passed i.e req.params.PARAMETER_PASSED. So i tried to install express-validation module by "npm install express-validation". but it generates an error like "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY joi@*" and I even wanna know what difference it makes if I use "npm install express-validation --save" what does --save mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does npm install say I have unmet dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies) for avoid `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY` problem.

you can use `--save` for add this dependency into your package.json file. If not it install relevant dependency into node_modules folder but will not add into package.json file.