# How could the vue-cli-service crash because of the '@vue/cli-plugin-babel' module, if the node module is there?

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

**Some background:**

I started my project with [a clone of this repository](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable). Here's [an example of the code](https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/custom-clone). After some time, I realized that the vue-cli-service it used appeared to be old. (They even renamed it to '@vue/cli-service'). So, I ran npm update. The code has me use `npm run serve` to start the service. It's apparently equivalent to `npx vue-cli-service serve`. When I did that, it couldn't load some bootstrap stuff. I reinstalled bootstrap (`npm install bootstrap@version` (don't have access to the exact line I used). It then said it couldn't find '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'. I saw it right in the node_modules folder.

**I fixed it using this process:**

1. I ran `npm update`.
2. It first said that it could not find a font (no longer have the specific details). The error directed to the bootstrap.css file.
3. I reinstalled bootstrap.
4. I run `npm run serve`, and it says "Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'"
5. I see '@vue/cli-plugin-babel' [showing in the node_modules folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MehOv.jpg)
6. I run `npm list --depth=0`, and '@vue/cli-plugin-babel' does not show up. 
   [I*’m seeing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vypWa.jpg)
7. `npm cache clean --force` alone did not cause the site to resume. It still said “ Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'”.
8. Following [the top SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies) got my site to work again.

   1. `rm -rf node_modules/`
   2. `npm cache clean` (then replaced with `npm cache verify` on npm's prompt)
   3. `npm install` (I wonder if it was possible to ignore ‘rm -rf node_modules/’ and just do the last two steps).
9. I run `npm run serve`, and the site works again.
10. After running npm list --depth=0 again, [there are no more UNMET DEPENDENCY issues, like with #6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWkOT.jpg).

Also on that SO Q&A, people talked about restructuring (reordering) the package.json file. In the top answer he says that a possible solution is to “Re-structure your package.json. Place all the high-level modules (serves as a dependency for others modules) at the bottom.”. I wonder if that relates to my issue.

**My expected vs. actual results:**

When I updated it, I actually sort of expected it to break. I got that.

But what I also expected was:

1. If the node module is there, it will not give me an error.
2. If I run `npm install`, all dependencies will be handled automatically.
3. If npm install doesn't do the trick, then `npm cache clean --force` should do the trick. (Note: I later learned about `npm cache verify`).

I got:

1. The '@vue/cli-plugin-babel' module was there *and* it gave an error saying it couldn't find it.
2. (And also 3.) Running `npm install` and `npm install [unmet-dependency]` did not work until after 'rm -rf node_modules/' -> `npm verify cache' and THEN -> 'npm install'.

**Here are my guesses:**

- @vue/cli service doesn’t check the folders directly to see if a module exists (75% chance it’s true)
- @vue/cli service uses a proxy, something like the packages.json file (but different) to see if a node exists (40%).
- @vue/cli service caches commonly used stuff. So, when I ran it again after the update, it didn’t check the new stuff in my folder, it checked its cache. It didn’t line up. (10%).
- For everything above, replace @vue/cli service with npm (10%).

Again, my biggest question is **"How could the vue-cli-service crash because of the '@vue/cli-plugin-babel' module, if the node module is there?"**

And **"How did removing the node_modules folder, verifying the cache, and reinstalling with npm cause `npx vue-cli-service serve` to successfully run my site again (and find @vue/vue-plugin-babel)?"**.