# npm install returning error

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install a project from GitHub and followed the installation instructions.  When I run npm install in the project directory it's returning the error results below:

```
root@server:/var/www/nomp# npm install
npm WARN colors@0.6.2 package.json: bugs['name'] should probably be bugs['url']
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bignum

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: request
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /var/www/nomp/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/nomp
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: request
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/nomp/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Does anybody know the issue?  I just installed nodejs and npm so I have no idea why this would happen.

Edit (ran after setting registry):

```
npm WARN colors@0.6.2 package.json: bugs['name'] should probably be bugs['url']
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bignum

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: request
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /var/www/nomp/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/nomp
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: request
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/nomp/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
root@pool:/var/www/nomp# vi npm-debug.log
root@pool:/var/www/nomp# vi npm-debug.log
root@pool:/var/www/nomp# npm install
npm WARN colors@0.6.2 package.json: bugs['name'] should probably be bugs['url']
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bignum

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: request
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /var/www/nomp/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/nomp
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: request
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/nomp/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
root@pool:/var/www/nomp# vi npm-debug.log
root@pool:/var/www/nomp# vi npm-debug.log
root@pool:/var/www/nomp# npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
root@pool:/var/www/nomp# npm install
npm WARN colors@0.6.2 package.json: bugs['name'] should probably be bugs['url']
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bignum
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.34.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.34.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser/-/body-parser-1.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/bignum
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bignum/-/bignum-0.6.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser/-/body-parser-1.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/bignum/-/bignum-0.6.2.tgz

npm ERR! Unsupported
npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: request@2.34.0
npm ERR! Required: ["node >= 0.8.0"]
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.1.4","node":"0.6.12"}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/nomp
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! message Unsupported
npm ERR! errno {}
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/type-is
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/qs

> bignum@0.6.2 install /var/www/nomp/node_modules/bignum
> node-gyp configure build

sh: 1: node-gyp: not found
npm ERR! error installing bignum@0.6.2
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body
npm ERR! error installing body-parser@1.0.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-0.6.6.tgz
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/nomp/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Answer (score 2):

I also hit into this error. It might be due to my network.

I work out as:

`npm --strict-ssl false install <pkg>`

This option sets validation on nodejs's CA as optional. I think it has the same effect as Sandile's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think an issue just like this one has already been answered to some degree here: [NPM installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359456/npm-installation-error).

But, to save you some time, try `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: I ran that and then did npm install.  Edited OP look at what it returned.

Comment: you could try `sudo npm install -g npm` first to make sure you're using the latest version of npm

Comment: I get an error: **module.js:472 throw err; Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'**

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same kind of problem with the same version of node and npm.

```
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
```

These are the versions that you get with ubuntu using apt-get.

To fix the problem, I removed the old versions:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

This removes node and npm. 
Then installed the latest:

```
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
sudo chmod -R a+rx /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

You can remove the install directory when you're done with it.
I got the script that I based this on from:
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814 which is linked to from: http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm/
The article is a little out of date. For instance, npm comes with node now.