# npm-install bignum Failing

Tags: node.js, npm, bignum

Attempting to install the bignum Node.js package using NPM, but I'm not having much luck. I'm using Windows 7 and running the command line as administrator. Have updated NPM to the latest version, using Python 3.4 and c:\Python34 is in my PATH (also tried Python 2.6 with similar results). Also tried the workarounds noted in this article: [npm install returning error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398274/npm-install-returning-error). Even tried an older version of bignum (0.8.0). Still, each time I try to install, I see the following:

```
> bignum@0.9.0 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\bignum
> node-gyp configure build

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\bignum>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_m
odules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" config
ure build
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:
34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\bignum
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bignum"
npm ERR! node v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bignum@0.9.0 install: `node-gyp configure build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bignum@0.9.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bignum package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bignum
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
```

Is there something I haven't done or am doing wrong, or is it with the package?

Kind regards,

Ryan

Comment: are you installing it locally or globally ?

Comment: Installing it on my local development machine.

Comment: I mean, try 'npm -g install bignum'

Comment: Yea, getting the same error with -g :(

Comment: try changing your Path to direct executable and not to the directory, PYTHON=%PYTHONPATH%\python.exe , this worked for two guys having the same issue.

Comment: did u solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (Error: spawn C:\Python34 ENOENT) trying to download     `socket.io`

```
npm install -g socket.io
```

I added an environment variable to point to the Python executable

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python34
set PYTHON=%PYTHONPATH%\python.exe
```

This resulted in the error message "Error: Python executable "C:\Python34\python.exe" is v3.4.3, which is not supported by gyp".

I then downloaded an older version of Python - 2.7.10 - and changed the environment variables to point to this older version

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27
set PYTHON=%PYTHONPATH%\python.exe
```

That solved my problem.