# Errors installing socket.io for node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I installed node on my windows 8 machine with no problems and then went to install the socket.io package to use for an assignment. After typing

```
npm install socket.io
```

I got a huge amount of errors.[image: npm install socket.io errors]

What I've tried so far:
this - [nodejs npm install socket.io error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590258/nodejs-npm-install-socket-io-error)
and this - [NPM - Can't install socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469086/npm-cant-install-socket-io)

The first answer in both.
A lot of the other stuff I'm finding is for either windows 7 or Mac so I'm not sure if this is just a windows 8 thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in logs you have a permission error. Script doesn't have enough permissions to create directory in `C:\\Program_Files\...`. Use other directory instead or run command with Admin permissions.

Comment: Was that all? Wow! what gives it away? Is it EPERM code showing up? Regardless it worked. Thanks!

Comment: "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator" is a good indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Try running
    npm install socket.io

except this time run the command line as an administrator. You can do this in Windows 8 by going to your app search, typing cmd, right-clicking then click 'Run as administrator'.

I feel this is the issue because your error message says 'Please try running this command again as root/Administrator'.