# can run npm install on phonecat application

Tags: angularjs

I am getting while following the tutorial at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00

```
angular-phonecat-master$ npm install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-server
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: protractor
```

logs from npm-debug.log are as follows

```
 verbose raw, before any munging shelljs
verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './shelljs' ]
verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: shelljs
ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)  

........
ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
```

Did anyone experience similar issue

Comment: Check the log file `/home/seneca/Downloads/angular-phonecat-master/npm-debug.log`. Might get some hints ..

Comment: I just did a fresh clone and ran npm install successfully, what happens if you run it again?

Comment: I am getting same error. Tried to run 'npm start' command. After looking closely i saw a message in log 'This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
'

Comment: It is resolved with solution at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/message-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-while-trying-to-install-any-module

Answer (score 1):

This might or might not work. But try to downloading your application using GIT instead of downloading the zip and then type in git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://.

I was having this issue when I was trying to download angular-seed project on windows 10. I installed GIT command line. Then Instead of downloading the ZIP, I used GIT command line to download the project. For the network issue I typed in git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:// as others have mentioned.