# Error in installing JShint in Vagrant environment

Tags: vagrant, jshint

Good day to all:

I had these error while installing JShint and CSS Linter thru my Vagrant environment.  I'm using Vagrant in Windows and Ubuntu is on my vagrant box.

I already installed npm and nodejs, tried lot of updates way but no luck.

Maybe others can shed a light.

Here is the error.

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ npm install jshint

vagrant@precise32:~$ npm install jshint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: jshint
npm ERR! at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR! at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-cient/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR! at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:
npm ERR! at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR! at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR! at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR! at ClientRequest.<anonymous (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR! at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR! at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR! at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR! <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use npm ERR!reportbug --attach /home/vagrant/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "jshint"
npm ERR! cwd /home/vagrant
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: jshint
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/vagrant/npm-debug.log
```

### npm not ok

Comment: You already seen  this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/message-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-while-trying-to-install-any-module

Comment: Yep but I got new error in initiating npm undate npm -g

Comment: which vagrant version your are using and which box?

Comment: Yes I got it now! Just read some comments threw and it works then! Thanks @GonzaloBahamondez

Comment: Im using vagrant 1.7.2

about the box im not sure, just used VDD (Vagrant Drupal Development) and precise32..

the box server is Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please respond with your `npm --version` and `node --version`. I suspect either out of data npm/nodejs libraries.

In either case, try this:

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Closed bug here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2119

**EDIT:** Perhaps this is an issue with Windows host to a Ubuntu VM:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7308

1. `npm install jshint --no-bin-link` If it installs, then your filesystem doesn't support links and each time you run `npm install`, you will need to append this flag. If you use this flag, you can't install globally with the `npm install -g` flag.
2. npm may not be detecting your host filesystem since npm is run on Ubuntu VM. You need to allow symlinks on Windows host in the Vagrantfile:

   ```
   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
       v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
   end
   ```
3. If you want to just bypass setting up Vagrantfile and ok with not installing global binaries (the -g flag), which I highly suggest not to, then alias your `npm install --no-bin-links`:

   ```
   echo "alias npm='npm --no-bin-links'" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
   ```

Comment: Thanks.  But I tried too but no respond on the terminal.  I ran sudo npm install -g npm@latest   but still having error

Comment: got it now @jojo thanks for the link.. it guides me to other links and wikis