# node.js npm install ws error "npm ERR! network" installing web sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, ubuntu, websocket, raspberry-pi

Having difficulty installing node sockets from my digital ocean server running Ubuntu 14.04, my aim is to stream from a raspberry pi to my web server though the web sockets following this tutorial http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets

I have followed the following similar question here and have gone through the solutions but still to no avail ["message failed to fetch from registry" while trying to install any module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/message-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-while-trying-to-install-any-module)

I am now met with the error after updating my nodejs and npm version

```
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "ws"
npm ERR! cwd /root
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.38
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and running `npm upgrade` fixed it. The problem was that the `package-lock.json` file had an old endpoint that didn't exist anymore for one of the dependencies. The upgrade command changed it to the current endpoint listed in the registry.