# Error while installing Bower

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I am trying to install bower but this gives me below error , which i am not able to decipher why , can someone share their experience or reason for the same

```
`home@home:/usr/local/share$ which npm
/usr/bin/npm
home@home:/usr/local/share$ which node
/usr/bin/node
home@home:/usr/local/share$ pwd
/usr/local/share
home@home:/usr/local/share$ cd npm
bash: cd: npm: No such file or directory

home@home:/usr/local/share$ sudo npm install -g bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: bower
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /usr/local/share/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-96-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/share
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: bower
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/share/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/message-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-while-trying-to-install-any-module see if this helps

Comment: your NPM version is ridiculously old. update it.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful ..trying to remove old installation resulted into some broken package warning , which i got resolved using aptitude. Updating npm version helps.