# How do I install shared memory package (shm) with npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I installed npm and tried using `npm install shm`.
I'm getting the following errors:

```
$ npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shm

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: shm
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
.......
.......
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vinayak/nodejs/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you behind proxy?

Comment: @Avinash mentioned is already, most likely you are facing some network issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["message failed to fetch from registry" while trying to install any module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/message-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-while-trying-to-install-any-module)