# Installing nodejs and npm on linux

Tags: node.js, npm

I have having a bit of an issue with installing nodejs and npm on my linux server (which is a pi running raspbian). I had everything set up and running using

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

All was fine and dandy, until I found out that apparently these versions are now old. So I removed them

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
```

Then I found the following answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/message-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-while-trying-to-install-any-module)) on SO and ran

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Running node -v have me version 0.6.19...which I'm assuming translates to version 6.19 as opposed to version 0. However, running npm -v told me that it was not installed. So I once again purged nodejs, and looked for another solution. At which point I decided to follow the stuff on nodejs's site ([here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)). And I ran the following commands.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

2 issues:

1) The version installed was still 0.6.19. I would rather have version 4.x, since that's what I'm running on my dev machine (macOS Sierra).

2) I still don't have npm. Which renders nodejs useless

Any help on either (but preferably 2) would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I really recommend you install node and npm using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). This is the fastest, cleanest and easiest way to do it.

That way, you install NVM simply doing:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | bash
```

To test that nvm was properly installed, close and re-open Terminal and enter nvm. If you get a nvm: command not found message, your OS may not have the necessary .bash_profile file. In Terminal, enter touch ~/.bash_profile and run the above install script again.

And you are now able to install node typing:

```
nvm install <version>
```

For example

```
nvm install 4.2.1
```

if you just want to install the latest node version, you can just type

```
nvm install node
```

In order to access node and npm as sudo (in order to have <1024 ports) you should run

```
n=$(which node)
n=${n%/bin/node}
chmod -R 755 $n/bin/* 
sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

Comment: Thanks @Luis González. I certainly owe you a beer. Why nvm isn't the first approach that pops up on google is beyond me. Super each and straightforward.

Comment: I'd like to add, that in order to access node and npm as sudo (in order to have <1024 ports) i had to run " n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local "

Comment: Thank you very much, Luis!  Also, if you just want to install the latest node version, you can just type `nvm install node` instead of `<version>`.

Comment: this is the best way doing it

Comment: I should point out that the URL that this post recommends you pipe into `sh` is some random github user's code. It's not official NVM account. Here's the URL that NVM suggests you use: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh

Comment: After I ran `nvm install` it said `No .nvmrc file found`.

Comment: I feel like this command is really dangerous: chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*

Answer (score 9):

I wrote in the terminal the following command lines
I hope it is useful for the community.

```
$ sudo apt install nodejs
$ curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, installing a specific version of the node.js from the authorized source does not work properly. It will be  better if will be installed after downloading the node package from the link(https://nodejs.org/en/) and following the steps....

1. Unzip the compressed package using the following command:

> `tar --xf node-v16.13.1-linux-x64.tar.xz`

2. Make a directory inside `/usr/local/`:

> `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/nodejs`

3. Move all unzip files to newly made dir:

> `sudo mv node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/* /usr/local/nodejs/`
> 4. Open `.bashrc` file using command prompt:

> `sudo nano ~/.bashrc`

5. Add the following command inside the `.bashrc` file at the end and
   close the file:

> `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nodejs/bin`

6. Print the path for justification:

> `echo $PATH`

7. Verify the node version:

> `node --version`

Answer (score 2):

Below are the simple steps to proceed with the installation

1. Open Terminal
2. Run command to install nodejs :
   sudo apt install nodejs
3. Run command to verify installation by checking version:
   node -v or node –version
4. Run command to install npm:
   sudo apt install npm
5. Run command to verify installation of npm:
   npm -v or npm –version

For reference:
https://youtu.be/DGjfw4y0nTI