# sudo apt install npm it is not working "The following packages have unmet dependencies"

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, web, npm

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs (>= 6.11~)

```
   Depends: node-ansistyles (>= 0.1.3~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-aproba (>= 1.2~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-archy (>= 1.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-cacache (>= 10.0.4~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-bluebird (>= 3.5.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-call-limit (>= 1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-chownr (>= 1.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-config-chain (>= 1.1.11~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-detect-indent (>= 5.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-detect-newline (>= 2.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-editor (>= 1.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fs-vacuum (>= 1.2.10~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fs-write-stream-atomic (>= 1.0.10~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-glob (>= 7.1.2~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 4.1.11~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-has-unicode (>= 2.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-hosted-git-info (>= 2.6~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-iferr (>= 0.1.5~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-inflight (>= 1.0.6~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-inherits (>= 2.0.3~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ini (>= 1.3.5~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-npm-package-arg but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-promzard but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-jsonstream (>= 1.3.2~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-json-parse-better-errors (>= 1.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lazy-property (>= 1.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-libnpx (>= 10.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lockfile (>= 1.0.3~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 4.1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-mississippi (>= 3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-move-concurrently (>= 1.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-nopt but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-normalize-package-data (>= 2.4~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-gyp (>= 3.6.2~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-resolve-from (>= 4.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-encoding but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-errno but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-npmlog (>= 4.1.2~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-once (>= 1.4~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-opener (>= 1.4.3~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-osenv (>= 0.1.5~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-path-is-inside (>= 1.0.2~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-promise-inflight (>= 1.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-qw (>= 1.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read (>= 1.0.7~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 2.0.13~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-request (>= 2.83~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-retry (>= 0.10.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.6.2~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-safe-buffer (>= 5.1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-semver (>= 5.5~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-sha (>= 2.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-slide (>= 1.1.6~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-sorted-object (>= 2.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-from2 but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-stream-iterate but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ssri (>= 5.2.4~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-strip-ansi (>= 4.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-tar (>= 4.4~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-text-table (>= 0.2~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-uid-number (>= 0.0.6~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-unique-filename (>= 1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-unpipe (>= 1.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-boxen (>= 1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-import-lazy but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-is-npm (>= 1.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-latest-version (>= 3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-semver-diff (>= 2.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-xdg-basedir (>= 3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-validate-npm-package-name (>= 3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-which (>= 1.3~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-wrappy (>= 1.0.2~) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-write-file-atomic (>= 2.3~) but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: This is not the whole output, is it?

Comment: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
this is last line of output...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate of several similar posts. As I recall, some linux distros don't work well with npm/node.js for installing with apt-get.

Check out, for example, this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39981888/10826737