# npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine on npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

Anyone familiar with the ff error when running `npm install` on an Angular project?

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@schematics/update@0.1102.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.12.1', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

Comment: Did you _read_ the error message? It tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

remove node_modules folder and try installing npm packages with `--legacy-peer-deps` flag

Comment: legacy peer deps can create a lot of version conflicts and tend to be vulnerable to security vulnerabilities. I recommend not using them

Answer (score 1):

In your case your missing `yarn` -> '>= 1.13.0'

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.12.1', npm: '8.19.2' }
```

[Here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install) is the instructions to install it

If you had an issue with (outdated) `node` after installing npm with `apt install npm` was it was my case, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39981888) instructions to up.